# Where do I post questions relating to software design approaches?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a question relating to software design and "How I should approach x". I'm not sure it's a "Stack Overflow" type question as it can be open to interpretation.

Does Stack have a better place to post these sort of questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Programmers Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) is a likely destination for such questions (so long as they are not overly open-ended).

From the Programmers [help center](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

**If you have a question about...**

- software requirements
- software architecture and design
- algorithm and data structure concepts
- quality assurance and testing
- development methodologies and processes
- software configuration management
- software engineering management
- software licensing

Answer (score 2):

You could try [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com), but please take our [tour](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tour) and read our [help](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help) - particularly the sections on

[What topics can I ask about here?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

and

[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)